# MS Access - copying Linked Tables between mdb's

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2003

I need to copy a large number of linked tables to another mdb, but I want them to stay links and not copies of the data.

I can drag-n-drop the table links between my two open mdb's - but that copies the data.

I've also considered writing a couple of VBA functions that look something like

```
Set db = CurrentDb
db.TableDefs.Refresh
For Each myTable In db.TableDefs
    If Len(myTable.Connect) > 0 Then
        '' export myTable.Name and myTable.Connect to a flat file (or table)
    End If
Next
```

and

```
Set db = CurrentDb
db.TableDefs.Refresh
For Each ''row in flat file
    Set tdf = db.CreateTableDef([myTable.Name])
    tdf.Connect = [myTable.Connect]
    db.TableDefs.append tdf
Next
```

Before I do so, is there an easier way that I've missed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you choose File->Get External Data->Import and import a linked table, you will find that it has imported a link, not the table itself.